# How to allow any user in JBoss config

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x

I have an access problem in a Java web application and I think that it's because of the rights of JBoss. 
I'm using JBoss 7.1. I found the files application-roles.properties and application-users.properties and I think that it's where we must assign the rights. Actually, I have nothing in these files.

I've searched about this conf but I don't find anything which can help me.

Can anybody help me to give all rights to any users please ? And maybe explain me how it works please.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding users to file is not going to do the trick. Here are the basic steps in adding authentincation and authorization in Java Web App.

1. Create a login module and define a JNDI name for the login module in
   the Java application server. There are many login modules to choose
   from such as LDAP, Database, UserProperties, Certificate, etc. This is where you can point the login module to the `application-user.properties` for principal authentication and `application-roles.properties` for the roles definitions.
2. Then you need to add proper web application security-constraints in your web.xml along with authentication type of basic or form. This is pretty standard configuration.
3. Finally, add the login module JNDI name in the `jboss-web.xml` file under WEB-INF (for a WAR file) or META-INF (for a JAR or an EAR file).

You can follow along this [example](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-security/securing-as-7-applications-using-the-applicationrealm) if you are planning to use the application-user and roles file for your application. Most organizations usually use LDAP or Database type of login modules for authentication since that's more scalable and secured. You can see a list of few other login modules [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Authentication+Modules).